# SQL - Using Union All and add duplicates

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am doing a query using Union All and I want to make sure that duplicate rows are added to the result query. When using Union All, duplicate rows are not added properly. When searching google for "sql union with duplicates", it states: "Union will remove duplicates. Union All does not. That you don't have already the duplicates in the first part of the query (maybe generated by the left join). As I understand it UNION it will not add to the result set rows that are already on it, but it won't remove duplicates already present in the first data set." In my case, I DO want to add the result set rows that are already in it. How would I do that?

Here is my query:

```
SELECT player_name_fkey, school_name_fkey, score_simple, sum(score_simple) over (partition by player_name_fkey) as sum_scores

FROM (

    SELECT player_name_fkey, school_name_fkey, SUM(score) as score_simple 

        FROM simple LEFT JOIN players on players.name=simple.player_name_fkey 

        WHERE category='Cadet' AND gender='Féminin' GROUP BY player_name_fkey, school_name_fkey

    UNION ALL

        SELECT player_name_fkey, school_name_fkey, SUM(score) as score_simple

        FROM double LEFT JOIN players on players.name=double.player_name_fkey 

        WHERE category='Cadet' AND gender='Féminin' GROUP BY player_name_fkey, school_name_fkey) t1

GROUP BY player_name_fkey, school_name_fkey, score_simple
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Try removing the `GROUP BY` clause at the end.

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by Felix Pamittan, removing the GROUP BY clause at the end solved my issue.

```
SELECT player_name_fkey, school_name_fkey, score_simple, sum(score_simple) over (partition by player_name_fkey) as sum_scores

FROM (

    SELECT player_name_fkey, school_name_fkey, SUM(score) as score_simple 

    FROM simple LEFT JOIN players on players.name=simple.player_name_fkey 

    WHERE category='Cadet' AND gender='Féminin' GROUP BY player_name_fkey, school_name_fkey

UNION ALL

    SELECT player_name_fkey, school_name_fkey, SUM(score) as score_simple

    FROM double LEFT JOIN players on players.name=double.player_name_fkey 

    WHERE category='Cadet' AND gender='Féminin' GROUP BY player_name_fkey, school_name_fkey) t1
```